# JIRA SOAP API : get the list of users

Tags: api, jira

I'm working on a tool in C# that interfaces the JIRA SOAP API. I have read the doc one can find here: http://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/rpc-jira-plugin/latest/index.html

Does anyone know how I could get the list of all the assignable users for a specific project? I haven't been able to find how to do that yet...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok I must be in better shape today so here is a solution of my problem

```
    /// <summary>
    /// object interface to the JIRA API
    /// </summary>
    private readonly JiraSoapServiceClient _JiraService;

    /// <summary>
    /// authentication token returned by the login method 
    /// that can be used on all other SOAP methods
    /// </summary>
    private readonly string _Token;

    /// <summary>
    /// name of the RemoteProjectRole "Developers"
    /// </summary>
    private const string DEVELOPER_ROLE = "Developers";

    /// <summary>
    /// id of the RemoteProjectRole "Developers"
    /// </summary>
    private static long? _DeveloperId;

    /// <summary>
    /// return the list of the names of all the users who have
    /// the role "Developers" in a project
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="project"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public List<string> GetUsersForProject(string project)
    {
        List<string> users = new List<string>();
        try
        {
            // get the RemoteProject
            RemoteProject rp = _JiraService.getProjectByKey(_Token, project);

            // get the "Developers" Prject Role
            RemoteProjectRole developerRole = getDeveloperRole();

            if (developerRole != null)
            {
                // we can use this method only if the user logged in is an administrator
                RemoteRoleActors actors = _JiraService.getProjectRoleActors(_Token, developerRole, rp);
                foreach (RemoteRoleActor actor in actors.roleActors)
                {
                    foreach (RemoteUser user in actor.users)
                    {
                        users.Add(user.name);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // TODO log the error

            users.Clear();
        }
        users.Sort();
        return users;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// return the RemoteProjectRole "Developers"
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private RemoteProjectRole getDeveloperRole()
    {
        RemoteProjectRole developerRole = null;
        if (_DeveloperId == null)
        {
            // the first time we call this function we don't know the id of this role
            // that's why we are obliged to find it with a foreach on all the project roles
            foreach (RemoteProjectRole role in _JiraService.getProjectRoles(_Token))
            {
                if (role.name == DEVELOPER_ROLE)
                {
                    developerRole = role;
                    _DeveloperId = role.id;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // we have the id so we can get directly the RemoteProjectRole from the JIRA SOAP API
            developerRole = _JiraService.getProjectRole(_Token, (long)_DeveloperId);
        }

        return developerRole;
    }
```

comments are welcome.
Obviously, we can use the same way for different role. One just has to be sure that the user used to log in the JIRA api has some admin rights

Answer (score 2):

Note that when calling getProjectRoleActors from Flex (at least), if your logged-in user is not an administrator, then instead of getting an error or empty response as one might expect, you get no response at all, which is very frustrating until you remember to make the user an admin.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit counter-intuitive as there's no general "Get Users" type command, and you need to load a project and role object before you can ask the question.

Here's the same basic implementation in PHP (since I just wrote it), but keying off the "Users" role rather than "Developers":

```
$base_url = 'https://yourjira.domain.com';
$wsdl = $base_url . '/rpc/soap/jirasoapservice-v2?wsdl';

$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';

$client = new SoapClient($wsdl);

try {
    $token = $client->login($username, $password);
}
catch (SoapFault $fault) {
    echo "Error logging in to JIRA";
    print_r($fault);
}

$code = 'MYPROJECT'

$project = $client->getProjectByKey($token, $code); 

$role = $client->getProjectRole($token, 10000); // 10000 is typically the "users" role

$users = $client->getProjectRoleActors($token, $role, $project);

print_r($users);
```