# Find all users of all projects with Jira API

Tags: jira

I need to get a list of projects for currently logged in user. I found the decision of oppozite task here: [JIRA SOAP API : get the list of users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093564/jira-soap-api-get-the-list-of-users)

Is there a way to do this through Jira API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean which projects a user is allowed to see issues in? If so, you want to use

getPermissionSchemes to retrieve an array of RemotePermissionSchemes, then use getPermissionMappings on each of those to get the permissions that you want to see, e.g. View Issues (by id). The problem is you'd have to do this for all projects (can be cached) but then getting the roles for the user only works for the logged in user.

summary: I'd write my own SOAP method to do this

Comment: thank you, it's very useful, but i mean all projects where user can be assignee, anyway your information will help me too

Comment: Ah ok. You'll need to get the permission scheme for each project and find the people who have the Assignable permission and go from there. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

These are 2 questions:

- Which users are currently logged in?
- List of projects for a user?

For the first one, I found some entries in the JIRA issue tracker: [Users currently logged on](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-1655)

The second one is easier, have a [look at the API](http://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/rpc-jira-plugin/latest/com/atlassian/jira/rpc/soap/service/ProjectServiceImpl.html#getProjects%28com.atlassian.crowd.embedded.api.User,%20boolean%29)

Comment: thank you for your response. API can give us project by key, we can see all users in project (this is what Jira does). But i need to get all projects for a certain user, not vice versa. Of course i could iterate through all projects, and find matches, but it's too expensive for my purposes.