# Jira Rest Api for getting full user list

Tags: rest, jira

How can I get the list of all users using Jira Rest Apis.

I have tried:-

```
/rest/api/latest/user/search?username=
```

Here I tried with blank username string but it doesn't return full user list. We only get some results when username is of at-least 1 length.

How can I get full users list from Jira rest API's ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the Rest API has this ability. As far as I know you'll have to choose a different way, for example you could use the [Soap API](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/Creating+a+JIRA+SOAP+Client) to do so as shown in this question [JIRA SOAP API : get the list of users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093564/jira-soap-api-get-the-list-of-users). Another way might be [querying the DB directly](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRACOM/Example+SQL+queries+for+JIRA#ExampleSQLqueriesforJIRA-Listuserswhohavenotcreatedissuessinceaparticulardate).

Comment: SOAP API is **"Supported but no future development"** also it is not recommended by Jira. https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/Creating+a+JIRA+SOAP+Client

Comment: Yea, they stopped developing the SOAP API and focused on developing the REST API, but for now the REST API is not complete, hence, usable for simple tasks only. The SOAP API won't be future developed, but will be supported in future releases as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a loop in which you will go through all letters and another loop to show result for each user whos name begins with this letter. something like this:

```
char[] ch = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};

int j = ch.length;
 for (int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++)
                        {
                            System.out.print(Character.toString(Character.toUpperCase(ch[i])));
                            --j;

String projects = invokeGetMethod(auth, BASE_URL+"/rest/api/2/user/search?username="+Character.toString(ch[i]));
                            System.out.println(projects);
                            JSONArray projectArray = new JSONArray(projects);
                            for (int k = 0; k < projectArray.length(); k++) {
                            JSONObject proj = projectArray.getJSONObject(k);
                            System.out.println("Key:"+proj.getString("key"));
}

}

 private static String invokeGetMethod(String auth, String url) throws AuthenticationException, ClientHandlerException {
        Client client = Client.create();
        WebResource webResource = client.resource(url);
        ClientResponse response = webResource.header("Authorization", "Basic " + auth).type("application/json")
                .accept("application/json").get(ClientResponse.class);
        int statusCode = response.getStatus();
        if (statusCode == 401) {
            throw new AuthenticationException("Invalid Username or Password");
        }
        return response.getEntity(String.class);
    }
```

Comment: That's a great hack! Does JIRA only allow userids to start with 26 characters? I know I've seen numeric userids and maybe ones with underscores as the first character

Comment: Yes, you right, it allows to use numbers in userid...
So basically you should add then numbers from 0 to 9 in list and try them too.

Answer (score 1):

`/rest/api/2/user/search?username=%` works.

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, one should always consider adding an explanation to it.

Comment: This no longer works. They don't allow searching on the username anymore

Answer (score 1):

[You can use](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/cloud/#api/2/group-getUsersFromGroup) `/rest/api/2/group/member?groupname=` if you're an admin user. Otherwise, this isn't available.

Answer (score 0):

I sometime use the SOAP getGroup method on jira-users to get the members of jira-users but it seems to miss some users out at around 5K, and you do have to run it as a JIRA admin user. A better way is to access AD directly if you can.

Comment: SOAP API is **"Supported but no future development"** also it is not recommended by Jira. https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/Creating+a+JIRA+SOAP+Client

Answer (score 0):

This is an example I use in perl. I am sure it can be improved but it works for me.
Just change 'user' and 'password' accordingly.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.10.0;
use Data::Dumper;
use JIRA::REST;

$Data::Dumper::Sortkeys = 1;

my $jira='http://jira:8080';

my $jirarest = JIRA::REST->new($jira, 'user', 'password');

my %users;

for my $c ( 'a' .. 'z', '0'..'9' ,'_') {
    say "Scanning '$c'";
    my @u =  @{$jirarest->GET("/user/search?username=$c&includeInactive=1&maxResults=1000")};
    say scalar (keys @u);
    @users{  map {$_->{name}} @u } =  @u;
}

say Dumper(\%users);

say scalar (keys %users);
```

The main assumption is that no single character has more than 1000 entries. I will investigate the startAt parameter and see if it's there to support some kind of paging.

Answer (score -1):

I wanted to get all the users in my email domain. Because JIRA searches username, displayName, and emailAddress with the username parameter, all I needed to do was to specify username=mydomain.com as the parameter and I got a full list of users in my email domain. If you want to broaden the search to multiple domains, try username=.com. Hth.