# get customfield value for jira issue using JIRA SOAP API

Tags: soap, jira

I want to get the values of all custom fields for a particular JIRA issue using SOAP API. I have a custom field named **'Phase'** having value **Decision Pending** for a JIRA issue **JIRA-123**.

I am using `JIRA 5.1.3`.

I am able to get all the properties of JIRA issue using SOAP API except the value of the  custom field for above issue.

I tried following code, but I am not able to use **ComponentManager** in my code

```
IssueManager issueManager = ComponentManager.getInstance().getIssueManager();
CustomFieldManager customFieldManager = ComponentManager.getInstance().getCustomFieldManager();
Issue issue = issueManager.getIssueObject("JIRA-123");
CustomField customField = customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObjectByName("Phase");
Object customFieldValue = issue.getCustomFieldValue(customField);
```

I would highly appreciate if anyone can provide correct approach.

Comment: The SOAP API is deprecated by 5.1.3. I suggest you use the REST API - it is both more easy to use and implement.

Comment: Thanks Borislav,
I am not quite familiar with REST API. Would appreciate if you can share some key pointers for fetching the custom field value for a JIRA issue using the REST API.

Comment: Thant's not so true.. it's not deprecated, to quote from Jira's site `Supported but no future development.`. The Rest API is still a bit new and there are things you can't yet do with the REST API, and can be done easily using the SOAP API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of how do you use the soap API, here is example of using it via the PHP-SOAP:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
   $soapClient = new SoapClient("https://jira.com/rpc/soap/jirasoapservice-v2?wsdl");
   $token = $soapClient->login('user', 'password');
   $myIssue = $soapClient->getIssue($token,"TES-13");
   print_r($myIssue); // all of the issue details
   print_r($myIssue->customFieldValues); // get all custom fields
   foreach ($myIssue->customFieldValues as $customFieldValue) {
        // search for the right custom field
        if ($customFieldValue->customfieldId == 'customfield_10402') {
                echo $customFieldValue->values[0];
                die();
        }
   }
?>
```

In case you want to use any other API, have a look at the [JIRA Remote API Reference](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+Remote+API+Reference).

A remark regarding the REST and SOAP APIs -To quote from Jira's site the SOAP API "Supported but no future development". The Rest API is still a bit new and there are things you can't yet do with the REST API ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631997/jira-rest-api-for-getting-full-user-list/11633197#11633197)), and can be done easily using the SOAP API.

Comment: Thanks Kuf, for your valuable feedback!

Answer (score 2):

The SOAP API is deprecated by 5.1.3. I suggest you use the REST API - it is both more easy to use and implement.

**What is REST?:** [read here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer). The basic idea is to bind HTTP request types to actions, it's quite obvious - check [this table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#RESTful_web_services) for a quick run-in.

Jira has a powerful REST API that you can use. This is [the main documentation](http://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/) of the current release.

**What do you need to do in some high-level steps?:**

1. Set-Up some type of authentication with your JIRA instance. Be it:

   - Baisc - [example](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+REST+API+Example+-+Basic+Authentication)
   - OAuth - [example](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+REST+API+Example+-+OAuth+authentication)
2. Get a list of all fields via the API:

   The `/rest/api/2/field' [method returns a list of all fields][6] - both System and Custom.
   Then when you identify the exact field use`/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/{id}` to get [the full

   representation](http://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#id123004) of the Custom Field Option.

I recommend you use a tools like [Chrome REST Console](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rest-console/cokgbflfommojglbmbpenpphppikmonn?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) ,or anything similar that you can easily make requests with, to get to know the API. The bonus is that you don't need to setUp authentication if you're logged in through the same browser. Your user will require full admin access though.

This is the [root of all JIRA REST API](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+REST+APIs) docs. Check it out.

If you're doing this in PHP I would personally recommend using some kind of library. I've used 
[Guzzle](http://guzzlephp.org/) (in a CakePHP environment) for this exact task and it turned out very well.

Comment: Important caveat. The JIRA server APIs are different from the JIRA cloud APIs. If you have server, you can't do what Borislav just explained as of November 2016. https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/cloud/ https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/server/